# Is css3 function target-counter() supported in the browsers like Chrome, IE etc?

Tags: css

When I print table of contents from html, I want to add the page number of each section to table of contents. So I am thinking using target-counter function. If it is not supported, is there any other way to add the page number? Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look at caniuse.com, or even a Google search? (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters might be what you want)

Comment: @BillyNate, thank you for your reply. But I cannot find target-counter, which can be found on http://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/, from the link you provided. So not yet supported?

Comment: The title of the page you mentioned says "draft", so I'm afraid it isn't supported (yet). Is there a reason you can't use css-counters and a "normal" url?

Comment: The reason I want to use target-counter is that I want to add page number of each chapter to table of contents when I print html, and I don't know other ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Up to now (April 2017), no browser support css-gcpm. Only the dedicated tools like [Prince](http://princexml.com/) support it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a polyfill for it called paged.js. See https://pagedjs.org/

It is not perfect, but it's not bad either. It is definitely usable.